# What happend, or where is the complete collection of Al Bukhari's original work

Tags: hadith, islamic-scholar, sahih-bukhari

It is known that Al Bukhari in his lifetime collected over 600.000 hadiths, and filtered them, resulting in 6 volumes with around 8.000 hadiths. What happend to his original 600.000 hadiths?

Comment: A huge amount of this is present in his books. But for his sahih al-Bukhari only quoted what is reliable and authentic according to his conditions. Imam Malik for example started his al-Muwatta' with around 10.000 narratives put of 300.000 of which 100.000 was the Hadith of az-Zuhri while the final version has only around 2.000 narratives.

Comment: The number 600k refers to the number of ahadith he memorized and learned before only writing the Sahih ones in his Sahih. It doesn't mean there was some original collection he trimmed down